# How can I use a regex to match a pattern only at a specific position in the string?

Tags: java, regex, substring, matching

Assume 4 strings, 2 to be matched the other not:

```
String string1 = "Hello World View";
String string2 = "Hello Nether World";
String string3 = "A World You should not find";
String string4 = "Any   World is good";
```

What regular expression will only match `string1` or `string4` where `World` starts in position
`6`?

Comment: Why don't you just match `\bWorld\b` and use the matcher's method to check the index where the match started?

Answer (score 3):

```
"^.{6}World"
```

Assuming you're using `Matcher.find` which doesn't require the whole string to match: `^` means "beginning of string", so this requires the beginning of the string to be followed by any six characters, followed by your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.matches(".{6}World.*")
```

Beginning, 6 characters, World

Comment: `String.matches` requires the whole string to match, so you need `.*` at the end of the regex.  (And you don't need `^`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=^.{6})World
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a regex a substr would be faster.

Pseudo code:

```
String strWorld = "World";  
String string1 = "Hello World View";  
bool bFound = false;
bFound = ( strWorld == string1.substr(6, strWorld.length()) ) ? true : false;
if ( bFound ) { }
```

Comment: The problem is that this throws an exception if `string1.length()` is shorter than 11.  Another check is needed.  (Also, what's the point of setting a `boolean` to `expr ? true : false`, instead of just `expr`?)

Answer (score -2):

You can use method `region()` to search on the part of the string. I your case:

```
matcher.region(6, str.length());
```